# What's the equivalent of the SEP metadata in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, csv, microsoft-excel

I'm using [the SEP metadata](https://superuser.com/q/773644/34623) in my csv files to enable people all over the world to correctly open them on MS Excel. It worked finely until recently some people wanted to open those files on Google Sheets which couldn't recognize this metadata.

So I have in fact 2 questions: What's the Google Sheets equivalent of this metadata (if there's one) and also is there an all around metadata which could work both on MS Excel and Google Sheets (and of course if possible on all spreadsheeting applications).

Answer (score 1):

> What's the equivalent of the SEP metadata in Google Sheets?

There isn't one.

> is there an all around metadata which could work both on MS Excel and Google Sheets

No.